# How can I apply base.html file for extending to every template in django

Tags: python, django, templates

Is there a way to extend base.html file in python django by default, I want it because I am overwriting {% extends  %} tag in every html file

Answer (score 0):

No but what you can do however is created a new HTML file called for example, `header-tags.html` with something like that :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
.... more tags
```

And then include this snippet wherever you want with {% include 'header-tags.html' %}